# Ruby | How to convert mail like numbers?

Tags: arrays, ruby, list, ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have an exercise where I have to make a program to program an email list from 1 to 50 in this format "jean.dupont.01@email.fr"

I have tried several methods, and I think I have found the right one, but it only converts the numbers. In the result obtained in the terminal I get the email address and the numbers in the array from 1 to 50. I would like this to display the mails 1 by 1 with the numbers changing,
thank you in advance.

```html
a = (1..50).to_a

puts "jean.dupont.#{a}@email.fr"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the emails one by one you can iterate over the `range` or `array` (using [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-each)) and interpolate each number in the email address

```rb
(1..50).each { |n| puts "jean.dupont.#{n}@email.fr" }

=> jean.dupont.1@email.fr
=> jean.dupont.2@email.fr
=> jean.dupont.3@email.fr
=> jean.dupont.4@email.fr
=> jean.dupont.5@email.fr
=> ...
```